# When to grow an interface, restrict it, or use implemetation to do so

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, interface, base-class

I often have trouble determining when to grow an interface or shrink it or use some implementation to do so.  Consider a matrix; it can either be square or not, so I'd say:

```
interface IMatrix<T>
{
  void InsertColumn(int position);
  void InsertRow(int position);
  void DeleteColumn(int position);
  void DeleteRow(int position);
  T ValueAt(int row, int col); //gets the value
  void ValueAt(int row, int col, T value); //sets the value
}
```

So, the above Matrix could be square, but it does not have to be.  My first idea was to use a class to create the idea of a square matrix as

```
class SquareMatrix<T> : IMatrix<T>
{
   private IMatrix<T> matrix;
   public SquareMatrix(IMatrix<T> matrix) {this.matrix = matrix;}
   public void InsertColumn(int position)
   {
     // Must ensure that a row and column are both added to keep it square
     this.matrix.InsertRow(position);
     this.matrix.InsertColumn(position);
   }
   // rest of methods similarly perform a row and column operation to keep square...
 }
}
```

However, I quickly realized that I could pass a square matrix into the constructor and get some bad results as now I'll be doing many additional operations.  So I feel like this is not a good approach for a way to restrict the interface to being only square unless there is a better way to implement this class.

So then I thought, well... square matrix is more restrictive than regular matrix, maybe I should extract an interface from that as...

```
interface ISquareMatrix<T>
{
  void InsertRow(int position);// adds a row and column, name selected for inheritance purposes
  void DeleteRow(int position);// deletes a row and column, ...
  void ValueAt(int row, int col, T value);
  T ValueAt(int row, int col);
}

interface IMatrix<T> : ISquareMatrix<T>
{
  void InsertColumn(int position);// adds only a column and now InsertRow should not also insert a column
  void DeleteColumn(int position);// deletes only a column
}
```

This seems OK, but somewhat breaks my train of though pertaining to inheritance since a SquareMatrix IS-A Matrix, and not vice versa.  Also, since I selected my names in a way that makes inheritance seem ok makes me cautious of this approach.

```
abstract class MatrixBase<T> : IMatrix<T>
{
  //Base class simply provides a matrix that we can use
  IList<IList<T>> matrix = new List<IList<T>>();
  public MatrixBase(int rows, int columns)
  {
    if(rows < 1) {/*throw ...*/}
    if(columns < 1) {/*throw...*/}
    // add rows and columns
  }

  public abstract void InsertColumn(int position);
  // more abstract methods to implement interface
}
class Matrix<T> : MatrixBase<T>
{
  //override all methods so that insert column only inserts a column
  //and insert row only inserts a row
}
class SquareMatrix<T> : MatrixBase<T>//seems fishy since matrix base is an IMatrix
{
  //override all methods so that insert row inserts a row and column
  //and insert column calls insert row
}
```

So as you can see, the square matrix is back to being a matrix though the interfaces would read in reverse.

Anyway, those are my thoughts; how would you model the relationship between a square matrix and a doesn't-have-to-be-square matrix?  :) Thanks!

Comment: Why bother having a square matrix at all? A square matrix is just a matrix with both dimensions having equal size. Are you going to give the square matrix type some special behaviours which should not be present on a non-square matrix?

Comment: See: [Circle-ellipse problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle-ellipse_problem)

Comment: Square matrix makes some things simpler to work with.  For instance, an adjacency matrix is always going to be square and I can add the ability to power the matrix since multiplication AxA will succeed on a square matrix only.

Comment: @Ani:  awesome, I thought there may be some research on this topic.

Comment: I understand that square matrices have special properties but should methods that take advantage of this be present on the object itself, or on the arithmetic engine that takes advantage of it? E.g. I can define a power operator which can have any matrix fed into it but will error if the matrix is not square.

Comment: True, I have that sort of thing setup as it is; however, it is still simpler to use a SquareMatrix than a Matrix since I have to remember to always add or delete both the row and column when I want to simulate a square matrix.  I suppose I could push that requirement to the users of the class.  Normally I try to add extension methods which take the engine as arguments so simulate a more natural connection between objects.  For instance, I can say (IMatrix<T>)a.Add((IMatrix<T>)b) where .Add is an extension method that looks up a default engine to use.

Comment: BTW - does this work have anything to do with the Stanford Machine Learning class?

Comment: @AdamRalph: No, this is an exercise in learning generics and extension methods while applying SOLID principals which has some application to a project I'm working on, but I could just as well have used a third party library.

Answer (score 0):

Generally the interface should only include methods that *all* implementations can sensibly fulfill. In this case I think the `AddRow` and `AddColumn` methods shouldn't be part of the interface but should instead be methods on `Matrix`.

In the .NET framework there are a few examples of interfaces that are overly broad and have `CanXxx` properties so that you can check whether or not a method makes sense for the specific object you have before calling it. So you *could* do this too I guess, but I'm not a big fan of it myself.

Comment: I do not want to have any of the classes as public and have a factory which returns IMatrix<T> typed objects.  Is this really not supposed to be in an interface?  If I take out the row adding and deleting then only the g/set values are left.  I feel like all matrices should be able to add rows and columns, only that square matrices must add both when adding either.